# How to convert dictionary values from string to list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, python-3.5

I have a dictionary in which the values are strings and I need them to be lists. So I tried to do:

```
for v in dic:
    v[1] = list(v[1])
```

However, it return an error that is,
*string index out of range*

My whole code is:

```
def agrupa_por_chave(lista):
    dic = {
        }
    for t in lista:
        if t[0] not in dic:
            dic[t[0]] = t[1]
        else:
            dic[t[0]] += t[1]
    for v in dic:
        v[1] = list(v[1])
    return dic
```

Comment: How `lista` looks like?

Comment: agrupa_por_chave([('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c')])

Comment: Add expected input and output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to get dict with string values replaced with lists:

```
>>> l = {1: 'abc', 2: 'def'}

>>> l
{1: 'abc', 
 2: 'def'}

>>> {k:list(v) for k,v in l.items()}
{1: ['a', 'b', 'c'], 
 2: ['d', 'e', 'f']}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
dic = {k: [v] for k, v in dic.items()}
```

or based on the clarification in the comment:

```
dic = {k: list(v) for k, v in dic.items()}
```

Comment: not quite. that return the whole value in a list and I need a list that contains each element of the value